# Pattern matching on the beginning of a string in f#

Tags: f#, pattern-matching

I am trying to match the beginning of strings in f#.  Not sure if I have to treat them as a list of characters or what.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Here is a psuedo code version of what I am trying to do

```
let text = "The brown fox.."

match text with
| "The"::_ -> true
| "If"::_ -> true
| _ -> false
```

So, I want to look at the beginning of the string and match.  Note I am not matching on a list of strings just wrote the above as an idea of the essence of what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 115, accepted):

Parameterized [active patterns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233248.aspx) to the rescue!

```
let (|Prefix|_|) (p:string) (s:string) =
    if s.StartsWith(p) then
        Some(s.Substring(p.Length))
    else
        None

match "Hello world" with
| Prefix "The" rest -> printfn "Started with 'The', rest is %s" rest
| Prefix "Hello" rest -> printfn "Started with 'Hello', rest is %s" rest
| _ -> printfn "neither"
```

Comment: +1. A nice example of active patterns for us wanting to learn as well!

Comment: This answer has a lovely application of compositions active patterns to string matching: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3686199/f-pattern-composition/3686555#3686555

Comment: This answer is fantastic, but I must admit I'm flummoxed. Where does the "rest" value come from in the match expression?

Comment: Take a look at the active patterns link in the answer, section partial active patterns. The rest comes from the underline (_) in the function definition.

Answer (score 26):

You could also use a guard on the pattern:

```
match text with
| txt when txt.StartsWith("The") -> true
| txt when txt.StartsWith("If") -> true
| _ -> false
```

Comment: This, too, was a good example, especially if you want to match partially on a switch containing an = and a parameter.

Answer (score 16):

Yes you have to treat them as a list of characters if you want to use a match expression.

Simply transform the string with:

```
let text = "The brown fox.." |> Seq.toList
```

Then you can use a match expression but you will have to use chars (the type of elements in the list) for each letter:

```
match text with
| 'T'::'h'::'e'::_ -> true
| 'I'::'f'::_ -> true
| _ -> false
```

As Brian suggest Parameterized Active Patterns are much nicer, there a some useful patterns [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/F_Sharp_Programming/Active_Patterns) (go the end of the page).

Comment: While I prefer Brian's answer using active patterns, I wonder if this one might be more efficient if the possible prefixes are only a few and not long. Any insights on this?

Comment: You have to create a temporary array and a F# list, so possibly lots of objects that would add pressure on the GC. This is not optimal at all. You'd better use two `StartsWith` or `StartsWith` + AP.

Comment: Since strings are already a `char seq`, you could just use `Seq.toList`.