# How can I extract the middle part of a string in FSharp?

Tags: string, f#, pattern-matching

I want to extract the middle part of a string using FSharp if it is quoted, similar like this:

```
let middle =
    match original with
    | "\"" + mid + "\"" -> mid
    | all -> all
```

But it doesn't work because of the infix operator + in pattern expression. How can I extract this?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3722591/pattern-matching-on-the-beginning-of-a-string-in-f

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't think there is any direct support for this, but you can certainly write an *active pattern*. Active patterns allow you to implement your own code that will run as part of the pattern matching and you can extract & return some part of the value.

The following is a pattern that takes two parameters (prefix and postfix string) and succeeds if the given input starts/ends with the specified strings. The pattern is not complete (can fail), so we'll use the `|Name|_|` syntax and it will need to return option value:

```
let (|Middle|_|) prefix postfix (input:string) =
  // Check if the string starts with 'prefix', ends with 'postfix' and 
  // is longer than the two (meaning that it contains some middle part)
  if input.StartsWith(prefix) && input.EndsWith(postfix) && 
     input.Length >= (prefix.Length + postfix.Length) then 
    // Strip the prefix/postfix and return 'Some' to indicate success
    let len = input.Length - prefix.Length - postfix.Length
    Some(input.Substring(prefix.Length, len))
  else None // Return 'None' - string doesn't match the pattern
```

Now we can use `Middle` in pattern matching (e.g. when using `match`):

```
match "[aaa]"  with
| Middle "[" "]" mid -> mid
| all -> all
```

Comment: Your implementation strategy is better than mine (only one call to `Substring`), but glad to see we had the same idea!  :)

Comment: Thanks Tomas. Your answer is so clear and helpful. Thanks to brian and kvb also. Unfortunately, I am new in StackOverflow and do not have enought credits to make your answers up.

Comment: @Brian: Yes, it looks like we posted almost the same answer! I also considered your strategy (but thought that checking length is easier) and I also considered passing the two arguments using a tuple :-)

Answer (score 4):

Parameterized [active patterns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233248.aspx) to the rescue!

```
let (|HasPrefixSuffix|_|) (pre:string, suf:string) (s:string) =
    if s.StartsWith(pre) then
        let rest = s.Substring(pre.Length)
        if rest.EndsWith(suf) then
            Some(rest.Substring(0, rest.Length - suf.Length))
        else
            None
    else
        None

let Test s =
    match s with
    | HasPrefixSuffix("\"","\"") inside -> 
        printfn "quoted, inside is: %s" inside
    | _ -> printfn "not quoted: %s" s

Test "\"Wow!\""
Test "boring"
```

Comment: Parameterized active patterns are amazingly powerful.

Answer (score 3):

… or just use plain old regular expression

```
let Middle input =
    let capture = Regex.Match(input, "\"([^\"]+)\"")
    match capture.Groups.Count with
    | 2 -> capture.Groups.[1].Value
    | _ -> input
```

Comment: Might be better to return an option type?

Comment: Author wants to return the whole string if it's not quoted, as I understood the question.

Answer (score 2):

Patterns have a limited grammar - you can't just use any expression.  In this case, I'd just use an if/then/else:

```
let middle (s:string) =
  if s.[0] = '"' && s.[s.Length - 1] = '"' && s.Length >= 2 then 
    s.Substring(1,s.Length - 2)
  else s
```

If grabbing the middle of a string with statically known beginnings and endings is something that you'll do a lot, then you can always use an active pattern as Tomas suggests.

Comment: Thanks kvb. I prefer Tomas' answer just because I do not want to use imperative way.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how efficient this is:

```
let GetQuote (s:String) (q:char) = 
        s 
        |> Seq.skip ((s |> Seq.findIndex (fun c -> c = q))+1)
        |> Seq.takeWhile (fun c-> c <> q) 
        |> Seq.fold(fun acc c -> String.Format("{0}{1}", acc, c)) ""
```

Or there's this with Substring in place of the fold:

```
let GetQuote2 (s:String) (q:char)  = 
    let isQuote = (fun c -> c = q)
    let a = (s |> Seq.findIndex isQuote)+1
    let b = ((s |> Seq.take(a) |> Seq.findIndex isQuote)-1)
    s.Substring(a,b);
```

These will get the first instance of the quoted text anywhere in the string e.g "Hello [World]" -> "World"